# Jquery, checking if a value exists in array or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I believe this question will be fairly easy for the ones who played around with java script / jquery.

```
var arr = new Array();

$.map(arr, function() {
 if (this.id == productID) {
   this.price = productPrice;
 }else {
  arr.push({id: productID, price: productPrice})
 }
}
```

I guess the code above explains what I want in really simple way. I would imagine this $.map would work like this but unfortunately I couldn't get results with this.

What is the most simple and elegant way to do this? Do I truly go through all array just to find if a key's value is there or not?

Does Jquery has something like `isset($array['key'])`?

**EDIT**

I tried to use inArray but it keeps adding object to array even if there is a match.

```
if ( $.inArray(productID, arr) > -1) {
   var number = $.inArray(productID, arr);
   orderInfo[number].price = parseFloat(productPrice);
}else {
   orderInfo.push({id:productID, price:parseFloat(productPrice)});
}
```

Comment: `$.inArray()` does not work most times. It's best to use `jQuery.inArray()`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to do it using `.map()` or just want to know how it works you can do it like this:

```
var added=false;
$.map(arr, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) {
 if (elementOfArray.id == productID) {
   elementOfArray.price = productPrice;
   added = true;
 }
}
if (!added) {
  arr.push({id: productID, price: productPrice})
}
```

The function handles each element separately. The `.inArray()` proposed in other answers is probably the more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Just 1 extra info; `added = true` must be inside of the condition.

Answer (score 232):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
if ($.inArray('example', myArray) != -1)
{
  // found it
}
```

Comment: Too bad community up-voting couldn't five years later result in something being marked as the right answer. :)

Comment: They should be marking the correct answers themselves by looking at the up votes after x amount of time

Comment: Actually `$.inArray` performs a === instead of ==. So if you do `$.inArray( "4", [1,2,3,4])` you will get -1

Answer (score 19):

jQuery has the `inArray` function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: I tried to use inArray but it seems I'm doing wrong at some point. It keeps adding data.

Comment: @Revenant, [**Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7881008/75500)'s an example.

Answer (score 16):

```
    if ($.inArray('yourElement', yourArray) > -1)
    {
        //yourElement in yourArray
        //code here

    }
```

Reference: [Jquery Array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)

The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0.

Comment: This is what i am looking for, Thanks a lot for coool solution

Answer (score 8):

Try [**`jQuery.inArray()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/SUKn2/) using the same code : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/SUKn2/

The $.inArray() method is similar to JavaScript's native .indexOf() method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, $.inArray() returns 0

**Example Code** :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         div { color:blue; }
         span { color:red; }
  </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>    
      <div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
      <div>4 found at <span></span></div>
      <div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
      <div>
         "Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so <span></span>
      </div>
      <script>
         var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
         var $spans = $("span");
         $spans.eq(0).text(jQuery.inArray("John", arr));
         $spans.eq(1).text(jQuery.inArray(4, arr));
         $spans.eq(2).text(jQuery.inArray("Karl", arr));
         $spans.eq(3).text(jQuery.inArray("Pete", arr, 2));
      </script>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
"John" found at 3
4 found at 0
"Karl" not found, so -1
"Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so -1
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. For those in the present future, use `jQuery.inArray()` instead of `$.inArray()`