# If an ID is in the list already, don't allow to add product

Tags: javascript, split

I'm making a simple shopping cart type thing in javascript and basically I only want one of each item to be allowed to be added. I have the following code, my plan was to split out the myIDs and then loop through to see if that number already existed but it falls over on the split and i'm not sure if that's the best way of doing it really.

Heres what I have, any help will really be appreciated. Thanks

> var myIDs;
>
> ```
> jQuery(".selectItem").click(function () {
>
>     if (myIDs) {
>         var split = myIDs.split(",");
>         alert(split[0]);
>     }
>     addToCart(jQuery(this).data('id'));
> });
>
> function addToCart(id) {
>
>     jQuery.ajax({
>         type: "GET",
>         url: "feeds/prodxml.aspx?id=" + id,
>         dataType: "xml",
>         success: function (xml) {
>             jQuery(xml).find('Product').each(function () {
>                 var sTitle = jQuery(this).find('Name').text();
>                 var sPublisher = jQuery(this).find('Description').text();
>                 jQuery("<li></li>").html(sTitle + ", " + sPublisher).appendTo("#addedItem ul");
>                 jQuery('.hide-on-click').remove();
>                 addItem(id);
>             });
>         },
>         error: function () {
>             alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
>         }
>     });
>
>
> }
>
> function addItem(itemID) {
>     if (!myIDs) {
>         myIDs = itemID;
>     } else {
>     myIDs = myIDs + "," + itemID;
>     }
>     alert(myIDs);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make myIDs an array instead of a string.

```
var myIDs = [];
```

Then you can modify the check to be

```
jQuery(".selectItem").click(function () {
if(jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).data('id'), myIDs){
    var split = myIDs.split(",");
    alert(split[0]);
}
addToCart(jQuery(this).data('id'));
```

});

```
function addItem(itemID) {
  myIds.push(itemID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I can see the logic - However I have the following code and when myids = nothing, it hits inside as if the id was in the array.  jQuery(".selectItem").click(function () {

        if (myIDs) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).data('id'), myIDs)) {
                    //do nothing
            } else {
                addToCart(jQuery(this).data('id'));
            }
        } else {
                addToCart(jQuery(this).data('id'));
        }

    });

Comment: Sorry. My condition should have been if( (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).data('id'), myIDs) > -1){  . jQuery returns -1 when the element is not in the array not false.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function can do this for you.

See: [Jquery, checking if a value exists in array or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880972/jquery-checking-if-a-value-exists-in-array-or-not)