# jquery if variable in a list of values

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery checking the choice made in a drop down.

```
function toggleFields() {
if ($("#chosenmove1").val() == 4)
    $("#hideme").show();
else
    $("#hideme").hide();
}
```

This works fine but I would like to change it so it checks a list of values like

```
if ($("#chosenmove1").val() in (3,4,5))
```

How can I write this to make it work (the above doesn't)

Tried a bit more

```
var arr = [3,4,5];
var value = $("#chosenmove1").val();
alert(value);

if ($.inArray(value, arr) > -1)
    $("#hideme").show();
else
    $("#hideme").hide();

}
```

The alert box tells me var value is getting the right value from the drop down - yet the show hide wont work under this setup.
IF I replace      var value = $("#chosenmove1").val(); with 
var value = 3; then it does work?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: `(3,4,5)` you mean array??

Comment: looks like that's what i mean - i want to check if the user has clicked on the drop down with the corresponding value of either 3,4 or 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery, checking if a value exists in array or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880972/jquery-checking-if-a-value-exists-in-array-or-not)

Answer (score 4):

Below is my working code: the array numbers needed to be in quotes?

```
function toggleFields() {
var arr = ['3','4','5'];
var value = $("#chosenmove1").val();

if (jQuery.inArray(value, arr) > -1)
    $("#hideme").show();
else
    $("#hideme").hide();

}
```

Comment: This answer is actually better if you're using strings.  `arr.indexOf` does not seem to play nice with strings in @Richard Macarthy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf

```
var arr=[1,2,3];

if(!arr.indexOf(1)){ // Your value here
    alert("exists");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xkcd8vko/1/