# How to Check if A Value exists in Array Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following scenario where my parameter array contains two arrays

```
 <script>
  var parameter = [];
  var brand;
  var category = [];

$(function() {
    $('#brand_category').click(function(event){
      var newhtml="";
      var Html = "";
      var cat_li = "";
      var $table = $('table#tablerow')
      var added = "";

      if($('input[name=brand]:checked').length<=0)
        {
         alert("Please Select brand")

        }

      if($('input[name=category]:checked').length<=0) {

        alert("Please Select Category")
      }

      else {
        cat = $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
        }).get();


        br = $("input[type='radio']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
        }).get();

        var found = jQuery.inArray(br, parameter);
        console.log(found)

        parameter.push({
          brand :   br,
          category: cat,
        });
 });

</script>
```

the parameter dictionary looks like this

```
Array[2]
0: Object
brand: Array[1]
0: "spykar"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
category: Array[1]
0: "Men Jeans"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
1: Object
brand: Array[1]
0: "Madame"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
category: Array[1]
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I want to push to parameter if the value doesnt exists and if it exists then it should not push.I tried to use inArray() but it always returns -1.What can be the problem .
What i want here is if the category is not already present then it should add to corresponding brand object.If present then it should not.similarly no two brands should be present

Comment: You only want to do the check for the brand or for the category as well?

Comment: What i want here is if the category is not already present then it should add to corresponding brand object.If present then it should not.similarly no two brands should be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i tried this solution after reading some answers**

```
$.map(parameter, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) {
      for (var key in elementOfArray.brand) {
        if (elementOfArray.brand.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (elementOfArray.brand[key] == br) {
                added = true
           }
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(added);

    if (!added) {
      parameter.push({
      brand :  br,
      category: cat
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't pushing just the value of `br`, you're pushing the values of `br` and `cat` as an object, you can't directly compare them using `inArray()`

For this to work, you will need to loop through `parameter` and test the value of each object inside it against `br`

```
var found = -1;
for (i=0;i<parameter.length;i++){
    if (parameter[i].brand == br) {
        found = i;
    }
}

if (found < 0){
    parameter.push({
        brand: br, 
        category: cat
    });
}
```

Comment: Not able to enter in the first if condition

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution ::

```
var parameter = [];

    cat = $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
    }).get();


    br = $("input[type='radio']:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
    }).get();

$.map(parameter, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) {

  if (elementOfArray.brand == br) {
   console.log('true');//do what you need on found

   parameter.push({
          brand :   br,
          category: cat
        });

 }else{
   console.log('false');//do what you need on not found
 }
});
```

ref :: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7881057/4119740)

Comment: You are pushing the data before checking it

Comment: The if condition is not matching ...check above

Comment: i just told you the logic of the checking and pushing arry......come on i have modified it as you said please check now.